# React - Creating table using loop in class method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, ecmascript-6

I would like to generate a table in `render() method` of my class.

So in different example/project in past, I have pushed divs to an array and then return this array and it worked fine in terms of displaying but in this case when I call `this.tableGenerator()` it displays the result as a plain text, not rendered HTML.

Can you please tell me why this happens? Or maybe there is another method I can loop this table out?

```
tableGenerator = () => {

    let table = [];

    table.push('<tr>');
    //loop for columns

    table.push('</tr>');

    return table;

}
```

Here is example I was talking about: it generates a board of divs and now I want to change it to display as a table:

```
createMap = (cols, total) => {
    let table = []; let nL = ''; let idRow = 0; let idCol = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < total; i++) {
      idCol++;
      if (i%cols === 0){
        nL = 'newLine';
        idRow += 1;
        idCol = 1;
      }
      else {
        nL = '';
      }

      let toggledBackground = '';

        switch (this.state.cellStates[i]) {
          case 1:
            toggledBackground = 'alive';
            break;

          case 2:
            toggledBackground = 'dead';
            break;

          default:
            toggledBackground = '';
        }

      table.push(<div id={"pos-"+idRow+"-"+idCol} className={"square "+nL+" "+toggledBackground} onClick={() => this.changeState(i)}></div>);
    }
    return table;
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
tableGenerator = () => {
  return (
    <table>
      <tr>
        {columns.map(column => <th>{column.data}</th>)}
      </tr>
    </table>
  );
}
```

Where column.data is the info you want to display (I used data as a general value but it could be label, name, info, etc).

Comment: Okay, but then why the example above works like a charm (divs)? 
//i have updateted original post

Comment: Because in your new example you are pushing strings with tags, in your old example you are pushing proper divs with JSX. Note the apostrophes in the new one.

Comment: See: JSX and how it works https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html    Plain tags in JSX is just syntactic sugar for React.createElement. If you write apostrophes around them you are just loading strings, not calling the important createElement function.